# Firebaseui phone authentication for web

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using firebaseui phone authentication to login user. I want to retrieve that phone number using JavaScript or jQuery.
Can someone help me out

Comment: What is your concrete problem you want to solve? Can you provide us your code? Please edit your Question.

Comment: I just want to retrieve the phone no. Of user so that i can store that phone no. In database

Answer (score 2):

First you [get the current user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile):

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

Then you [get the phone number from that user profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#phoneNumber):

```
var phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
```